# NestJS builds project in the `tsconfig` shared package where the shared tsconfig is located instead of app folder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, monorepo, turborepo

I have a turborepo based monorepo that looks something like this:

```
├── apps
│   ├── nest-app1
│   └── nest-app2
└── packages
    └── tsconfig
        └── nest.json
```

The issue I'm having is when I run build at the root level, because the tsconfig.json in `apps/nest-app1/tsconfig.json` extends the `packages/tsconfig/nest.json` configuration, the dist folder gets added in: `packages/tsconfig/dist` instead of `apps/nest-app1/dist.

Any ideas how to get it to build in the right location?

my nest.json config:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json in `apps/nest-app1`:

```json
{
  "extends": "@myapp/tsconfig/nest.json",
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"]
}
```

and the tsconfig.build.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Short anwser:**
Add the setting below into your nest-app1 and nest-app2's tsconfig.json may work.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
```

**Long answer:**
I also use  a turborepo based monorepo.
And the folder structure is similar like you.

```
├── apps
│   ├── nest-app1
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── nest-app2
│       └── tsconfig.json
└── packages
    └── tsconfig
        └── base.json
```

This setting below works for me.

```
apps/nest-app1/tsconfig.json (apps/nest-app2/tsconfig.json also the same)

{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```